# Ping addresses from a txt file

Tags: python, parsing, ping

Attempting to ping addresses from a file and print the results out to the end user.

script:

```
import sys
import ipaddress
import subprocess
import os
import re
import sys
from tabulate import tabulate
#Main routine
def main():
    address = sys.argv[1]
    pingthis = ['ping', '-c', '1', address]
    r = (subprocess.run(pingthis, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, check=True,).stdout.decode('utf-8'))
    pingtable = tabulate([[address, (re.search(r'time=(\d+)', r).group(1))]], headers=["IP", "TimeToPing (ms)"], tablefmt="simple",)
    pingfile = open("pingfile.txt", "r+")
    with open("pingfile.txt", "r") as fin:
        for line in pingfile:
            response = (subprocess.run(pingthis, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, check=True,).stdout.decode('utf-8'))
            if response == 0:
                with open("pingfile.txt", "w") as fout:
                     fin.write(pingfile)

    print(pingtable)
#Call main() function
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Getting a `raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args, subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['ping', '-c', '1', 'ingfile.txt']' returned non-zero exit status 2`. Is there more I need to add when opening the pingfile.txt and writing to it? Why would I get an error for `ingfile.txt` when the code says `address`?

Answer (score 1):

Your very syntax highlighter shows you have 2 "" after the "w" in the `open` statement, your quotes aren't balanced

```py
with open("pingfile.txt", "r") as fin:
    for line in pingfile:
        response = (subprocess.run(pingthis, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, check=True,).stdout.decode('utf-8'))
        if response == 0:
            with open("pingfile.txt", "w"") as fout: # <-- this line
                 fin.write(pingfile)
```